# how to sign in or sign up with one auth for all user ?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
        ]);


    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'], 'active' => 1]))
    {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Email address and Password mismatch or account not yet activated.');
}
```

i want access to open my project with one auth for all users 
if soemoene know to method can you tell me

Comment: What do you mean by one Auth?

Comment: for example that'S email: azerty@gmail.com and password :azerty, i want all users open with this email and pasword

Comment: One way you could do it is make a seeder that adds a user with the email of that and the password of that and then when they login it takes you to the dashboard and just dont link up the register so noone can make an account

Comment: well you can change registercontroller `create` part, assign static email and pass and. just request username from your blade file. in that case all users have different username but same email/password.

Comment: just create the user account ( email and password ), on post login just login the user with email and password account that you want

Comment: i dont understand your idea can you explain more @Diego Cespedes